# Navigating through textboxes with arrowkeys in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like the question says, how can i navigate through textboxes with my arrowkeys in HTML? Except using jQuery if possible. Maybe using JS? Or using HTML, CSS or something? Thanks!

```
<body>
        <form>
            <input  type="text">  <br>  
            <input  type="text">  <br> 
            <input  type="text">    
        </form>


    </body>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you could try doing something like this?

```
$('form').bind('keypress', function(event) {
  if(event.which === 38) { //up
    $(':focus').next().focus();
  }
  else if(event.which === 40) { //down
    $(':focus').prev().focus();
  }
});
```

not sure how to translate this to pure js

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery then? Can you put a console.log in to make sure the keypress event is happening.. maybe log the event.which

Comment: you'll also have to make sure that a checkbox has focus in order for this to work

Comment: I don't know how to use jQuery, I only know a bit of it and that's it. I have no idea on how to resolve this problem as far as I know

Comment: are you importing jquery on your page? put `console.log(event.which, $(':focus').length)` within the function. Open developer tools on your browser F12 and run your project. Press key up and key down and let me know what logs come through to the console (in developer tools)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have checkboxes in your HTML, but let's assume you will later.

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    var leftArrow = 37;
    var rightArrow = 39;
    //get other codes from http://keycode.info/
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes; i++){
        //find the focused checkbox in the node list
        if(checkboxes[i] === document.activeElement){
             //if it's found, then find the next one in the node list according to the keycode
             if(e.keyCode === leftArrow){
                  (checkboxes[i-1] ? checkboxes[i-1] : checkboxes[checkboxes.length - 1]).focus()
             }

             if(e.keyCode === rightArrow){
                  (checkboxes[i+1] ? checkboxes[i+1] : checkboxes[0]).focus()
             }
             //need to get out of this loop
             break;
        }

    }

})
```

Comment: I meant textboxes, I apologize

Comment: That's fine, just change the selector at the top. It'll work for those too.

Comment: I did. I changed it to `('input[type="text"]')` but what do I have to change your `checkboxes` to?

Comment: Nope, that's just a variable. But you change it around the code if it makes more sense for you.

Comment: You're right! I haven't noticed, my bad. Anyway. I have saved the file and checked my console, it gave me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: Huh, that's odd. Well you could try selecting the form instead on the body I suppose. You might need to wrap this in a function that runs when the document finishes loading.

Comment: And how do I do that? Like `document."form".addEventListener('keyup', function(e){` this?

Comment: That's a basic thing you'll need to learn about JavaScript. I heavily recommend you just read up on this topic; specifically how to select elements in the DOM.

Comment: Will do. Thank you. As a side note, I have tried wrapping it up in a function and "onloading" it in my body, like this `<body onload="textboxes()">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138149/discussion-between-brooku-and-fauxserious).